# Dynamic link events not getting registered by Firebase Analytics

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-analytics, firebase-dynamic-links

I was integrating Firebase Dynamic Links to my Android project. Following this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/#implementation-path).

Note: I just skipped 3rd step (Handle Dynamic Links in your app), since I don't want to handle it explicitly.

Everything is working fine, except that the dynamic link events (`dynamic_link_first_open`, `dynamic_link_app_open`, `dynamic_link_app_update`) which is supposed to collect automatically by [Firebase Analytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/analytics) are not getting recorded.

Other default events like `session_start`, `first_open`, etc. are getting recorded properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you can't skip the third step . It's required in order to track these events. You don't have to *do* anything with the data you get back from the server (though you really **should**, for the benefit of your users), but you do at least need to make the SDK calls.

Comment: For now i wanted to get only events for adword campaigns using firebase analytics thats why i omitted 3rd step. And yes when i added 3rd step it worked.